# How can i regain functionality with automatic downloads? they no longer work in either direction

Tags: iphone, ipad, applications, ios-appstore

I cannot get applications I download on my iphone to appear on my ipad.  Nor vice versa.  I did not have this problem with my old devices so I know it worked at one time.

Is this feature restricted to "new" purchases?  AKA if i'm trying to re-download something I already purchased in the past, it wont auto download to other devices?

I have ensured everything is signed in on the same appleid and both devices have auto downloads and auto updates on. I have tried toggling it off and on. Both are connected to the same wifi network.  Both have been restarted and are on the newest version of ios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New purchases download to all iOS devices, if configured so.  But an existing purchase does not download to iOS device #2 just because iOS device #1 installs it again after it has been removed.

It has always been so.

Comment: okay, i imagine ive been tearing my hair out for hours for nothing then.  i set up all my devices as new, and so apart from icloud data they were barren.  These were purchases made before i wiped the devices however.

I'll test by downloading something ive never owned before and if it functions I'll mark this as the answer.